# Launching jarsigner on linux machine on which JDK\JRE not installed

Tags: java, linux, jarsigner, jar-signing

I want to use jarsigner on a linux machine where I don't have JDK and JRE installed.

I tried to copy bin\jarsigner and lib\tool.jar on machine and set java_home to the location where I copied "bin" and "lib" folder. On Windows I am not use jarsigner by copying following files in folder and setting it as JAVA_HOME

```
\bin\jarsigner.exe,
\bin\msvcr100.dll,
\bin\jli.dll,
\lib\tool.jar
```

How to achieve similar thing in Linux?

Comment: By far the easiest way is to install a JRE.

Comment: JRE doesn't contain jarsigner, so i have to install JDK to use jarsigner. But my requirement is this only that I can't install JDK